# 'True' is not a valid value for property 'IsDragSource'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a strange problem with a WPF Dependency Property:

```
/// <summary>
/// attached property that defines if the source is a drag source
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragSource", 
        typeof(bool?), 
        typeof(DragDropBehaviour),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, 
            new IsDragSourceBehaviour().PropertyChangedHandler));
```

When I try to use it from my XAML window, it gives me curly lines.

```
<ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         AllowDrop="False"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Objects, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         i:DragDropBehaviour.DragDropHandler="{Binding}"
         i:DragDropBehaviour.IsDragSource="True" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

... stating that 'True' is not a valid value for property 'IsDragSource'. True should be a valid property value for Dependency Property of type (bool?) should I say.

What is my mistake?

The application works fine though, but I don't like red, curly lines in my XAML.

Comment: Have you tried re-building the solutions? It will go away.

Comment: Yes, several times, doesn't help...

Comment: Does it need to be nullable? Have you tried it with `bool`?

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening the XAML files? Closing and reopening the solution? Prior to VS 2013, the XAML designer always seemed to have issues caching old versions of assemblies and/or error messages.

Comment: Please see solution above in Edit...

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the original poster:

> I found it, the reason was found in two Get/Set methods:
>
> ```
>    /// <summary>
>    /// attached property that defines if the source is a drag source
>    /// </summary>
>    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragSourceProperty =
>       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragSource",
>       typeof(bool?),
>       typeof(DragDropBehaviour),
>       new PropertyMetadata(null, new IsDragSourceBehaviour().PropertyChangedHandler));
>
>    public static void SetIsDragSource(DependencyObject o, bool? propertyValue)
>    {
>        o.SetValue(IsDragSourceProperty, propertyValue);
>    }
>
>    public static bool? GetIsDragSource(DependencyObject o)
>    {
>        return (bool?)o.GetValue(IsDragSourceProperty);
>    }
> ```
>
> They were using object instead of bool?